# Git with multiple remotes

Tags: git

I have the following setup: I have a laptop (L), a central machine (S for server) and a stationary PC (P).

P and S are in the same LAN. A git archive can easily exchanged using one remmote tracking branch for each branch on S. All right.

Now the problem is with L: It can be in the LAN. Then it uses direct connection to S via IP. It can also be outside the LAN. Then a SSH connection to another machine (R for router) has to be opened with a port forwarding tunnel. Then on L you can access S through the tunnel.

I added a remote `origin` for master using the LAN-IP of the server. Now I added a second remote using `git remote add server.intern ssh://localhost:2222/...` and fetched the remote branch `remotes/server.intern/master` correctly. Now I tried to push the active branch (master) through the tunnel using `git push server.intern`.

I get the error:

```
fatal: You are pushing to remote 'server.intern', which is not the upstream of 
your current branch 'master', without telling me what to push
to update which remote branch.
```

I do not know how to tell git that I have two upstream branches for master. For now I can append the keyword master but it would be nice if there is a solution.

Thanks

Comment: You can't have two upstream branches in Git. While Git allows you to use an arbitrary web of connections between repositories, it's slightly geared towards making tree-like hierarchies. The "upstream branch" functionality lets you define the primary links in the tree and push/pull along these links with less typing. For secondary links you have to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I even found a better solution (thanks to a link on an other question): I added

```
[alias]
    rpush = "!ssh -f -L 2222:server.intern:22 example.net sleep 5 ; sleep 1 ; git push server.intern"
    rfetch = "!ssh -f -L 2222:server.intern:22 example.net sleep 5 ; sleep 1 ;  git fetch server.intern"
```

to my `.git/cinfig` file. Now I do no more have to call ssh manually and I do not need multiple consoles. Now I just call `git rpush master` or whatever branch I want to push.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two upstreams in Git, but you can provide push urls.  If all you're really looking to do is maintain a backup, or something similar.  You can do this for your origin:

```
git remote set-url --push --add origin <origin-url>
git remote set-url --push --add origin <alternate-url>
```

This will push to both the `<origin-url>` and `<alternate-url>` whenever you push to origin.  It's not quite the best setup if `<alternate-url>` is also present as a remote.  It the remote references won't be updated until the next fetch, but it's worked enough for me for years now.